# Co-relate cpu & mem usage from kubectl top pods and top command inside respective pod

Tags: performance, kubernetes

I wish to understand co-relation between "kubectl top pods" output and linux command "top" executed inside POD.
How do they co-relate ?

While top shows current load/usage status along with 5-min & 15-min details, do we have any such functionality for kubectl top pods command ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the shared information was helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

[Kubectl top](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top) - Allows you to see the resource consumption for nodes or pods. This command requires Metrics Server to be correctly configured and working on the server.

The **top** command is used to show the Linux processes. It provides a dynamic real-time view of the running system

If you run top inside the pod, it will be like you run it on the host system because the pod is using the kernel of the host system. Unix top uses the proc virtual filesystem and reads /proc/meminfofile to get actual information about current memory status. Containers inside pods partially share /proc with the host system include a path about memory and CPU information.

For more  information refer to [top command in linux](https://www.unixtutorial.org/commands/top) and [Kubernetes Top pod/node](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubectl-top-pod-node-for-metrics) authored by Kasper Siig.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for comment. Does that mean we will never be able to co-relate both as both are referring different source for reporting? There are high chances that "top" command executed inside POD may show us some results & at the same time "kubectl top pods" may show us different CPU core/mem usage. I am going through the link on "kubectl top pod". Thanks for kind help. I am trying to investigate more on this topic.

Comment: Yes, we can't co-relate both. if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting (✔️) or up voting it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Comment: I would prefer to access latest comment as answer which clarifies the doubt. I have upvoted it anyways. Thanks again !